# Angular ng-repeat performance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am fairly new to AngularJS and am having performance problems on an application I have built using ng-repeat.

Below I have listed a snippet from the page with performance problems (there isn't much else on the page).

The app I am working with has to be very dynamic (multi-tenant solution that is completely configurable) and for that reason the UI is dynamic.

I am assuming the problem is that there is a nested ng-repeat. THe page takes about 8 seconds to load.

There are about 10 setting groups that contain 157 (total across all groups) settings (which are tr's).

Can anyone advise me where I am going wrong and the best way to debug performance issue with Angular please?

```
    <form name="settingsForm" novalidate ng-submit="vm.save()">

        <h3>Settings</h3>

        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <strong>Deleting settings</strong> You can only delete settings that are not being used in any quotes.
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="template">Template</label>
                    <select id="template" name="template" class="form-control" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in vm.templates" ng-model="vm.selectedTemplateId" ng-change="vm.getSettingGroups(item.id)"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <fieldset ng-repeat="settingGroup in vm.settingGroups track by settingGroup.id">
            <legend>{{::settingGroup.name}}</legend>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{::settingGroup.settingNameColumn}}</th>
                            <th>{{::settingGroup.settingValueColumn}}</th>
                            <th ng-if="settingGroup.showSettingValue2">{{::settingGroup.settingValue2Column}}</th>
                            <th>{{::settingGroup.settingDescriptionColumn}}</th>
                            <th class="text-center" ng-if="!settingGroup.lockNameField" style="width: 40px">Hidden</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 30px">
                                <span class="btn-table" ng-click="vm.addSetting(settingGroup.id, settingGroup.settingItems)" ng-show="settingGroup.canAdd">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus text-success"></i>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in settingGroup.settingItems track by item.id">

                            <td class="form-group" ng-if="settingGroup.lockNameField">
                                {{::item.name}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group" ng-if="!settingGroup.lockNameField" show-errors>
                                <input name="{{::settingGroup.name + $index}}-name" ng-model="item.name" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-change="vm.modifySetting(item)" required>
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group" show-errors>
                                <input name="{{::settingGroup.name + $index}}-value" ng-model="item.value" type="number" class="form-control input-sm" ng-change="vm.modifySetting(item)" required>
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group" ng-if="settingGroup.showSettingValue2" show-errors>
                                <input name="{{::settingGroup.name + $index}}-value2" ng-model="item.value2" type="number" class="form-control input-sm" ng-change="vm.modifySetting(item)" required>
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group" ng-if="settingGroup.lockNameField">
                                {{::item.description}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group" ng-if="!settingGroup.lockNameField" show-errors>
                                <input name="{{::settingGroup.name + $index}}-description" ng-model="item.description" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-change="vm.modifySetting(item)">
                            </td>
                            <td class="form-group text-center" ng-if="!settingGroup.lockNameField">
                                <input name="{{::settingGroup.name + $index}}-hidden" ng-model="item.hidden" ng-checked="item.hidden" type="checkbox" class="" ng-change="vm.modifySetting(item)">
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <span class="btn-table" ng-really-click="vm.deleteSetting(settingGroup.settingItems, $index, item)" ng-really-message="Are you sure you want to delete this setting?" ng-show="settingGroup.canDelete">
                                    <i class="fa fa-remove text-danger"></i>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="">
            <hr />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'load', do you mean to render in the first place, or to load some data? If you need to render 1570 elements (157 * 10) it shouldn't take 8 seconds. Maybe a noticeable lag but not that long...

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the answer, 8 seconds is probably unacceptable for the user as this is going to be a commercial application. How can I get around the issue?

Comment: @PeterAshwell I guess meant: do you have your data - $scope.settingGroup.settingItems - already available when page is opened? As a static JSON object? Or probably you're loading it though some ajax call - then maybe the reason for 8 sec delay is there?

Comment: Yes, if the data takes 8s to load from the server that would explain the bulk of the problem. How much data is being loaded from the server? If you look at the network tab in your browser how long does the API request take?

Comment: The Ajax call is not the issue, I replaced the td's with one empty td colspan=7 and the table loaded instantly, suggesting it is a binding problem.

Comment: Does CPU profiling using the Chrome devtools help show where the problem is? Also, you are using some non-standard directives, I would remove them first to see if maybe they are causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicions about the performance problems:

- That ng-change function call (vm.modifySetting) is perhaps getting called on the first render. Can you check if it is being called or not using console log or a performance tool?
- ng-if might save on DOM elements, but it can actually lock up the DOM while it's removing / adding stuff. Although memory wise it might be better, try changing them all to ng-show and see if there's a performance improvement. Consider rewriting the elements and their listeners to not need the ng-if

Maybe look at using scalyr-ng-repeat (sly-repeat) as an option if it's not some basic mistake like above:

https://github.com/scalyr/angular